# Common Ribbon Control in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ribbon

I want to develop windows forms application in which i want same ribbon control to appear on top with same Click Functions associated. Is there any solution to add same ribbon to all forms? I tried MDI, but i dont have requirement of multiple documents to be opened at same time. I tried adding same ribbon to all forms one by one, but then , i need to create click methods for all buttons in all forms seperately, that is tedious and time waste.

Also, i need to know any solution for smoothing transition between form change. When i use code:

```
Form f1=new Form();
f1.show();
this.hide();
```

This works correctly for switching between forms, but the problem is it creates a jerk on screen. So, is there any solution for smooth transitioning of forms?

Comment: Create a base form, add the ribbon to the base form and then let every form (the ones you want to have the ribbon) inherit from the base form.

Comment: But when i inherit from my customribbonform, layout in visual studio changes, and on clicking form name, designer view is not opened.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a base class that implements the ribbon. Just reuse (that is: derive from) that control for every form you have.

Create a container under the ribbon where you can put your actual form content in.

A problem might be that the designer often doesn't like this, so it might be quite some work to smooth thing out.